# Masking a mobile number using regex in JavaScript/Groovy

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to mask a mobile number using replaceAll
masking should be like this

`+1(123)456-7890 ----> +1(2**)4**-**78`

`+11234567890 -----> +12**4****78`

`+1-123-456-7890 --->+1-2**-4**-**78`

I tried to use the code:

`test.replaceAll("\\d(?!\\d{0,3}\$)", "*")`

but it masks all the digits except the last 4.

Comment: Please select the language, because JS is quite different from Java/Groovy. Also, do you need to validate the strings while masking, or are these strings pre-validated?

Comment: the strings are pre validated, i just need to substitute the digits with *

Comment: Good, what is the language? A solution will be very language specific, please make your question specific.

Comment: Shouldnt the examples end in 90 rather than 78?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regular expression

```
(\+1[(-]?)\d(\d)\d([)-]?\d)\d{2}([)-]?)(\d{2})\d{2}
```

to match the entire string and replace the string with

```
$1$2**$3**$4**$5
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xbFqsj/1/)

Javascript's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(\+1[(-]?) # match '+1' opt. followed by '(' or '-' in cap grp 1
\d         # match a digit (discard)
(\d)       # match a digit in cap grp 2
\d         # match a digit (discard)
([)-]?\d)  # match a digit opt. preceded by ')' or '-' in cap grp 3
\d{2}      # match 2 digits (discard)
([)-]?)    # optionally match ')' or '-' in cap grp 4
(\d{2})    # match 2 digits in cap grp 5
\d{2}      # match 2 digits (discard)
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your input after looking at the solution from with your demo i saw the masking match in the question was wrong the masked value should have been +1(1**)4**-**90 updated the question also
basically i am looking to mask everything except the first digit of the area code, first digit of number and last 2 digits of the number
how can i modify it to work that way?

Comment: You cannot change your question after answers have been posted, as it makes those answers incorrect. Please click "edit" to "roll-back" to your original question. I can help you get what you want if you leave a comment on my answer. First, however, study my solution to your original question and see if you can figure how to modify it to meet your requirements.

Comment: Further to my previous comment, I suggest you go to the "Demo" link I provided and try changing my regex to get what you want. The results of each change will be visible immediately.

Comment: i understand your point and i have rolled back the question to the original question.
from the solution you providedi understood the basic concepts and i see that \ the $1, $2 values are basically being replaced by what matches in the reg ex groups however what i did not understand is $2 that is the second matching group takes the value of 2 instead of 1 why? and how could i change it to get what i want?
Thanks

Comment: I was able to figure out how it worked its the () that are capturing the values 
Thanks you for all your help